# Beans Binding in JTextField doesn't work

Tags: java

I tried to work with beans binding in Java. I followed code in some sites. And tried to make it work.

Here, what I did is, tried to update Person's first name with the value entered in textfield by user during the run time. But when I click the button, it contains "omg". if I replace that with "" it contains that value. As I refer it looks like work only once. What's wrong with it? What did I miss here? Can anyone help to resolve this?

I interchanged source and target and tried that also

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

    public abstract class AbstractModelObject {
        private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
                PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName,
                PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName,
                    listener);
        }

        protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue,
                Object newValue) {
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue,
                    newValue);
        }
    }

    import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
        import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

        public class PersonImpl extends AbstractModelObject implements Person{
            private String firstName; 
            private String lastName; 

            public PersonImpl()
            {

            }

            public PersonImpl(String firstName)
            {
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }

            public String getFirstName()
            { 
                System.out.println("getFirstName");
                return firstName;
            }

            public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
            { 
                System.out.println("setFirstName");
                String old = this.firstName;
                this.firstName = firstName; 
                firePropertyChange("firstName",old,firstName);
            } 
        }


        public interface Person {

            void setFirstName(String string);

            String getFirstName();

        }

            public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
                JTextField field = new JTextField("omg");
                JButton button = new JButton("Save");
                Person p = new PersonImpl();

                MyFrame()
                {

                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("first name : " + p.getFirstName());
                        }
                    });
                }
                private void initDataBinding() {
                    if(Beans.isDesignTime()){return;}
                    BeanProperty<Person, String> fNameProperty = 
                            BeanProperty.create("firstName"); 

                    BeanProperty<JTextField, String> textProperty =
                            BeanProperty.create("text"); 
                    BindingGroup bindingGroup = new BindingGroup();



AutoBinding<JTextField, String, Person, String> firstNameBinding
                    = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ, field, textProperty,p, fNameProperty);
                    firstNameBinding.bind();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this sort of binding would be created with READWRITE. That doesn't seem to be the root of your issue, but something to consider changing.

The first thing to check here is to put a breakpoint on the binding create call and make sure it's actually getting called.

If it is, consider adding a binding listener before you call .bind() and see if it reports any failed binding operations. That should help you track down the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: It is adding listener when .bind() is invoked. And there is no any failed binding operation.. :(

Comment: Did you add a binding listener to the binding? If so, post which listener callbacks get called...

Comment: Oops.. Which means I should add addPropertyChangeListener? I haven't added that.. Is it mandatory or optional?